# Is there a Kotlin equivalent of setReadOnly()?

Tags: kotlin

Is there an equivalent of Java function `setReadOnly()` for files in Kotlin?

Comment: Err, setReadOnly()? Kotlin has no specific File class. You use java.io.File, and thus have access to the same methods.

Answer (score 3):

Java and Kotlin can interop with one another without issue (i.e. [you can call Java from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html) and [vice versa](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html)), so you should still be able to just use the `setReadOnly()` function in any Kotlin classes by including the appropriate reference to `java.io.*` or `java.io.File` respectively:

```
// Notice the Java reference in this Kotlin class
import java.io.*

object ExampleKotlinProgram {

@JvmStatic
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Get your file (File is exposed through Java's java.io reference above)
    val file = File("C:\\your-file.txt")

    // Use the setReadOnly() call to check if it can be access or set to read only
    if (f.setReadOnly()) {
        // Indicate it could be set to read only
        println("File set as Read Only")
    } else {
        // Indicate it couldn't be set to read only
        println("File cannot be set as Read Only")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That's certainly true for Kotlin/JVM.  (As far as the JVM is concerned, classes are classes, whatever they were compiled from — and they can all access each other.)  I'm not so sure about other targets, though.